# Adding multiple shared preferences keys to the flipper shared preferences plugin

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, flipper, fbflipper

I was wondering how to show multiple shared preferences keys in the Flipper Shared Preferences Viewer Plugin. `KEY_FOO`, `KEY_BAR`, `KEY_BAZ` are string constants for shared preference files.

Something like

```
class App: Application() {

     override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        setupFlipper()
     }
    
     private fun setupFlipper() {
         if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && FlipperUtils.shouldEnableFlipper(this)) {
            val client = AndroidFlipperClient.getInstance(this)
            client.addPlugin(InspectorFlipperPlugin(this, DescriptorMapping.withDefaults()))

         
            client.addPlugin(
                SharedPreferencesFlipperPlugin(applicationContext, KEY_FOO)
            )

            client.addPlugin(
                SharedPreferencesFlipperPlugin(applicationContext, KEY_BAR)
            )

            client.addPlugin(
                SharedPreferencesFlipperPlugin(applicationContext, KEY_BAZ)
            )

            client.start()
         }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon inspection of the constructor for SharedPreferencesFlipperPlugin. A second option exists where it takes a list of SharedPreferencesDescriptor's.

Solution below.

```
class App: Application() {

     override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        setupFlipper()
     }
    
     private fun setupFlipper() {
         if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && FlipperUtils.shouldEnableFlipper(this)) {
            val client = AndroidFlipperClient.getInstance(this)
            client.addPlugin(InspectorFlipperPlugin(this, DescriptorMapping.withDefaults()))

            val keys = mutableListOf(
                KEY_FOO,
                KEY_BAR,
                KEY_BAZ,
            )

            var descriptors: List<SharedPreferencesFlipperPlugin.SharedPreferencesDescriptor> = keys.map {
                SharedPreferencesFlipperPlugin.SharedPreferencesDescriptor(it, MODE_PRIVATE)
            }

            client.addPlugin(
                SharedPreferencesFlipperPlugin(applicationContext, descriptors)
            )

            client.start()
         }
     }

}
```